# Links appear multiple times in Sharepoint 2010 Welcome menu

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have an issue where scripts are loading multiple times causing the Welcome menu (by the users name in the header) to have multiple references "My profile" and "My Site"

I have the issue on both the custom master page and the unmodified v4.master inspecting with firebug reveals SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js being loaded dynamically multiple times.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/SP.UI.MyLinksRibbon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still no answer to this...

Answer (score 1):

This problem on occurs when images are loaded into a custom webpart via a javascript template.  I think the scriptmanager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server"  
     EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true"
     EnableScriptGlobalization="false" 
     EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
```

This includes a call to
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(_myLinksRibbonLoad2, 'SP.Ribbon.js');
The js returns a "loaded" response to the function for each image which causes it to fire each time, loading the script into the header.

Comment: I tried loading the images only after the page loads with a jquery ready block. The problem still occurs. Something in the load event is trigging the script to get loaded muliple times.